# How to concatenate videos until a certain video length is reached FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have some videos that I need to concatenate, but only until the video length has reached 10 minutes. How do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-t 00:10:00` output option with the concat demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -t 00:10:00 output
```

If your videos do not have the same parameters use filtering to conform them, then use the concat filter to concatenate them.

See:

- [FFmpeg Documentation: concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat)
- [FFmpeg Documentation: concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)